# How to keep selected boolean fields based on computed result in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a scenario, where need to keep selected boolean fields based on computed result before saving record, so how can i do this?

Here is my code :

```
option = fields.Boolean(string='option') 
selected_option = fields.Boolean(compute='check_value', string='Selected')



@api.multi 
def check_value(self):
    for result in self:
        if result.option == True:
            result.selected_option = True
        result.selected_option = False
```

Comment: Correct the indentation to understand what `check_value` do, because it seems that your code always sets the `selected_option` to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
selected_option = fields.Boolean(compute='check_value', string='Selected', store=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the onchange function for Boolean field (Option)

```
option = fields.Boolean(string='option') 
selected_option = fields.Boolean(string='Selected')

@api.onchange('option') 
def check_value(self): 
    for result in self: 
       if result.option == True: 
            result.selected_option = True 
       else: 
            result.selected_option = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Code :

```
option = fields.Boolean(string='option') 
selected_option = fields.Boolean(compute='check_value', string='Selected')

@api.depends('option') 
def check_value(self):
    for result in self:
        if result.option:
            result.selected_option = True
        else:
            result.selected_option = False
```

Comment: @Mani In python, it is better to use `if result.option` instead of `if result.option == True:` as you can find at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008 `Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==`